# Regex to make last letter capital

Tags: regex, notepad++

SO i got regex to make first letter capital but i need now a regex to make the last letter caps, ive tried google searches and came up with nothing

Example of what im talking about

```
razor123

james333

firefire32923932

laser
```

Need them to turn into

```
razoR123

jameS333

firefirE32923932

laseR
```

Comment: I suggest you try [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) it's a great place to learn about regular expressions and try them out.

Comment: thanks ill do that, but still doesnt help me with my question and problem

Comment: **Try this.**

    var str = "laser"

    str =str.replace(/.$/,str[str.length-1].toUpperCase())

Comment: @ArifH-Shigri `1` don't answer question in comment. `2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Find: `^([a-z]+)([a-z][^a-z]*)$`
Replace with: `\1\U\2`